# Create sparse word matrix in Python (bag-of-words)

Tags: python, data-science

I have a list of text files in a directory.

I'd like to create a matrix with the frequency of each word in the entire corpus in every file. (The corpus is every unique word in every file in the directory.)

*Example:*

```
File 1 - "aaa", "xyz", "cccc", "dddd", "aaa"  
File 2 - "abc", "aaa"
Corpus - "aaa", "abc", "cccc", "dddd", "xyz"
```

*Output matrix:*

```
[[2, 0, 1, 1, 1],
 [1, 1, 0, 0, 0]]
```

My solution is to use `collections.Counter` over every file, get a dictionary with the count of every word, and initialize and a list of lists with size *n* × *m* (*n* = number of files, *m* = number of unique words in corpus). Then, I iterate over every file again to see the frequency of every word in the object, and fill each list with it.

Is there a better way to solve this problem? Maybe in a single pass using `collections.Counter`?

Comment: What libraries are you using from the scipy stack, if any?

Comment: Do you really need the full matrix, or would a sparse representation suffice?  A list of dictionaries (yes, Collections.Counter is very good) might do the job for you.

Comment: @IgorRaush None. Only Collections.Counter.

Comment: @ihmpall, I can't think of a way to solve your problem in a single pass over the files; what you have now may be your best option. Think about it: if you don't know your corpus ahead of time, you can't initialize the file vectors to the correct dimension, so even if you build your corpus and collect nonzero indices in a single pass, you'll need another pass to convert those nonzero indices into vectors.

Comment: One minor optimization within your existing approach is to use a `set()` during the first pass instead of a `Counter()`. If you are simply trying to build the corpus, you don't need a `Counter`. In any case, I strongly urge you to consider a sparse matrix implementation like `scipy.sparse.csr_matrix`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Below is a fairly simple solution which uses [`sklearn.feature_extraction.DictVectorizer`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.DictVectorizer.html).

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction import DictVectorizer
from collections import Counter, OrderedDict

File_1 = ('aaa', 'xyz', 'cccc', 'dddd', 'aaa')
File_2 = ('abc', 'aaa')

v = DictVectorizer()

# discover corpus and vectorize file word frequencies in a single pass
X = v.fit_transform(Counter(f) for f in (File_1, File_2))

# or, if you have a pre-defined corpus and/or would like to restrict the words you consider
# in your matrix, you can do

# Corpus = ('aaa', 'bbb', 'cccc', 'dddd', 'xyz')
# v.fit([OrderedDict.fromkeys(Corpus, 1)])
# X = v.transform(Counter(f) for f in (File_1, File_2))

# X is a sparse matrix, but you can access the A property to get a dense numpy.ndarray 
# representation
print(X)
print(X.A)
```

```
<2x5 sparse matrix of type '<type 'numpy.float64'>'
        with 6 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
array([[ 2.,  0.,  1.,  1.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.]])
```

The mapping from words to indices can be accessed via `v.vocabulary_`.

```
{'aaa': 0, 'bbb': 1, 'cccc': 2, 'dddd': 3, 'xyz': 4}
```